# How to make dynamic tree menu from database?

Tags: php

I want to use the library: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu to create a dynamic menu in html using the database. I have created a table with the menu structure

[image]

Once I see the documentation on: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/blob/master/doc/01-Basic-Menus.markdown#creating-a-menu-from-a-tree-structure

How do I extract the data from the table? What should be included in the array? If yes how examples of use?

Previously, I created a class that will do the queries to extract the menu to view. It's just that I feel using a query like this is too wasteful of memory. My class like this :

http://pastebin.com/eS2B5aQU

Is there a better way to save memory with a single query wherein I will get the same results?

Comment: Is there going to be a limit on how many levels there will be?

Comment: I want unlimited limit from the menu -> submenu

Comment: Also, just looking at your pastebin code, do you need to use the knp menu or do you just want something that will build the menu?

Comment: Why tag this Yii and mysql (now removed)?